# web.xml for jersey servlets not working

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey

I am following some examples to create REST services using jersey.

I am able to deploy the service and receive a welcome message from index.jsp, but I am not able to GET the resource defined in the REST service.

Below is my class and web.xml

```
package com.test.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/test")
public class test{

@GET
@Path("/{param}")
public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

    String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>first servlet</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

URI to access: `http://localhost:8080/PresenceRepositoryApp/rest/test/nice`

Error I am getting is **HTTP Status 404 - Not Found**

I checked the web.xml and compared from examples but can't find what is missing. I know something must be very silly but am not able to figure out.

Comment: Hi! How are you deploying? Tomcat? What do you see in the log? Has the servlet started up? I guess you don't use any ResourceConfig class. If you had one, you could check that your servlet is starting. You would have to change your init params to add the Application object instead of defining the packages. Anyhow, your configuration seems fine and indeed must be something silly. I would make sure first that you servlet is starting properly. If you want, add the log to your post. Good day and good luck.

Comment: Thanks Irnzcig. I am not using ResourceConfig class and have no idea about that also but I will try to find out how to use that. I would appreciate if you can provide some example. :)
Regarding this question, this is working now with same set of code. What I think is it's eclipse who is the culprit because once this code started working my other code in the same workspace started giving errors. Only thing I did was to go into the project properties > compiler > compiler compliance. Project was using J2se5 and I made it to 1.7. and again reverted to 1.5. Seems strange but this is what I did.

Comment: Weird but I believe it. Eclipse sometimes behaves in a weird way when switching Java versions. However I would use Java7 unless you really have to stick to Java5. About the definition of your application, take a look to: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.7/deployment.html. You should define an object like in Example 4.2, and then change your web.xml as in Example 4.9. In my opinion, it is something that sooner or later you should do. Defining resources in your web.xml is only ok for a quick try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat server then change your web.xml as follows.

Replace org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer 
with com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with tomcat. They are 2 different container jar and it depends which one you are using. I am using glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

Its too late to answer but it can help someone like me. :)

It seems that, the URL is not correct.

URL should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/first servlet/rest/test/nice
```

PS: don't forget to try %20% for space if required.